# PHP: Custom page landing for users

Tags: php, authorization, url-routing, laravel

I am building an application and my customer wants to implement a basic authentication system with group permissions. All good.

The problem I want to tackle is that he wants to be able to set for each user group the default landing url, when they log in. He wants to do that via form, so it can't be hardcoded.

**For example**: Administratror's default url would be

> myapp/dashboard

and the Writer's would be

> myapp/write

At first i wanted to create the table for all url and connect them to groupPermissions table, but it look a bit redundant.

My app is build with Laravel PHP Framework.

**PROBLEM**: What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: When you say "basic authentication" do you mean HTTP basic authentication? I ask because using HTTP basic authentication would really limit you with regards to how your application interacts with the authentication mechanism.

Comment: Is each user only given one group? Make a table with the group name and the app/path pairing. Then look it up when they finish logging in. If they can have more than one group, I'd consider establishing roles augmented by groups and use the role to match for a URL fragment.

Comment: @MikeBrant what do you mean by that? I am using Laravel filter to check the logged-in user's permission against permissions table.

Comment: How many different user/page connections will you have?

Comment: Hm..the problem is not setting the url, i have a problem with the hardcoded part.. How can i get all the url's of the app? @dmikester1 there are is one-many relation with users table to roles table. So many user can have 1 role and 1 role can be assigned to many users.

Comment: Laravel is an MVC isn't it? Can you list the views? I was assuming you were going to build some custom "landing" views too. Is a writer just going to be plopped onto a screen with a text editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how flexible you want the system to be. If the URI path is going to be changed in the admin panel, then storing the URLs in some sort of config and loading them when logging in would be the way to go.

For what I believe you want, I would define the URIs in a group as constants:

```php
<?php

class Group extends Eloquent {
    const ADMIN_URI = 'myapp/dashboard'; // Could also be named routes.
    const WRITER_URI = 'myapp/write';
}
```

Then you can login a User and fetch their permission group, then do a check like this in the login controller:

```
if(defined($redirectUri = sprintf('Group::%s_URI', strtoupper($groupName))) {
    return Redirect::to(constant($redirectUri));
}
```

or something like:

```
switch(strtolower($group)) {
    case 'admin':
        return Redirect::to(Group::ADMIN_URI);
        break;
    case 'writer':
        return Redirect::to(Group::WRITER_URI);
        break;
    default:
        return Redirect::to('homepage');
        break;
}
```

It's really a matter of opinion. The only concern you should have is a centralized place for how to store the URI routes and accessing them uniformly.